# .Net object validation frameworks

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm working on an ASP.NET project using MVP architecture.  We would like to use an object validation framework in the domain, but are not that familiar with available frameworks other than the Castle.Components.Validator namespace.

Does anyone have experience with any other light-weight object validation frameworks.  If not, what approach do you use to validate in the domain (no ASP.NET validator control answers please)?

Comment: This question was asked 33 minutes ago and is already in Google...wow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309509.aspx) in the Enterprise Library
[.NET Validation Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/ValidationFramework) on CodePlex
[EViL - Entity Validation Library](http://www.codeplex.com/evil) on CodePlex
[Validation Everywhere](http://www.codeplex.com/valever) on CodePlex

Comment: Validation Application Block isn't actually 'light-weight', but I do really like it.

Comment: Except VAB, the other three are no longer actively developed.
[Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/validation.html) seems to have some validation framework.
Fluent Validation, as @ilmatte mentions, is still active.

Answer (score 1):

I like the easy approach of the Fluent Validation framework. You find it on codeplex at:

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

You can gain the separation between entities and validators that you cannot get with Annotations (e.g.: Enterprise Library).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the MVP pattern, but this guy seems to know what he's doing. [Here's how he handles validation with MVP.](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/01/15/extended-mvp-pattern---domain-validation.aspx)