# Server side validations and unit testing in MVP

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, unit-testing, mvp

We are following passive controller approach and when user clicks on submit, server side validations are fired. There are many other fields on the screen that needs to be validated.

I would like to get feedback about the following approach.

1. Is it ok to have validations in Presenter.
2. As there are many fields in UI, `PerformServerValidations()` method is getting big. Is there any way I could refactor it.
3. Intention behind declaring `PerformServerValidations()` as public and returning a IList is to be able to test it. Is it a good approach to take?

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void Presenter_PerformServerValidations_ValidateFromCustomerId_ExpectFalseForInvalidNumber()
   {
       //creating presenter
       presenter.View.Stub(x=>x.FromCustomerId).Return("one two three");    

       var errorCodes = presenter.PerformServerValidations();

       Assert.IsTrue(errorCodes.Contains("ERR_InvalidFromCustomerId"));
   }
   ```

**Presenter.cs**

```
public void OnSubmit()
{
    var serverValidationErrors = PerformServerValidations();
    // View.ServerErrors will loop over the list and sets validator's IsValid property to false
    this.View.ServerErrors = serverValidationErrors ; 
    if(!serverValidationErrors.Any())
    {
         BindCustomers();
    }
}

public IList<string> PerformServerValidations()
{
   var errorCodes = new List<string>();

   int parsedFromCustomerId;
   int parsedToCustomerId;

   bool isValidFromCustomerId = int.TryParse(this.View.FromCustomerId, out 
parsedFromCustomerId);
   bool isValidToCustomerId = int.TryParse(this.View.ToCustomerId, out parsedToCustomerId);

   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.View.FromCustomerId) && !isValidFromCustomerId)
   { 
       errorCodes.Add("ERR_InvalidFromCustomerId");
   }

   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.View.ToCustomerId) && !isValidToCustomerId)
   { 
       errorCodes.Add("ERR_InvalidToCustomerId");
   }

   if((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.View.FromCustomerId) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.View.FromCustomerId) && (isValidFromCustomerId && isValidToCustomerId))
   { 
       if(parsedFromCustomerId > parsedToCustomerId)
       {
           errorCodes.Add("ERR_InvalidCustomerIdRange");
       }
   }

   //There are many other fields to be validated
   return errorCodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is ok to validate on the presenter. You could also validate some simple stuff (like typos and so on) at the client.
2. If you feel you have a way too long validation method or too much repetition between presenters, you could create validator objects which would receive information about the forms/views you want to validate user input on.
3. I don`t see so many problems with that. If your validation is complex enough to require unit testing, I would definitely move them out of the presenter into one or more validation classes.

Maybe you should check what people say here: [.Net object validation frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219385/net-object-validation-frameworks)